# Are structs limited to one slot in size?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I have some odd results.

Code -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract CA3 {

    struct  Student {
        uint16  age;
        uint16  income;
        uint16  score;
        uint16  attendance;
        uint128  studentTranscript;
        bytes32  studentAccount;
    }

    struct ShortStudent {
        uint16 age; 
        uint16 income; 
        uint16 score; 
        uint16 attendance; 
        uint128 studentTranscript;
    }

    struct Employee {
        uint16 age;
        uint16 income;
        uint16 timeWorked;
    }
    Student[] public students;
    Employee[] public employees;
    ShortStudent[] public sstudents;
    function setStudent (uint16 _age, uint16 _income, uint16 _score, uint16 _attendance, uint128 studentTranscript, bytes32 studentAccount) public {
        Student memory tempStudent = Student({age: _age, income: _income, score: _score, attendance: _attendance, studentTranscript: studentTranscript, studentAccount: studentAccount});
        students.push(tempStudent);


    }
    function ssetStudent (uint16 _age, uint16 _income, uint16 _score, uint16 _attendance, uint128 studentTranscript) public {
        ShortStudent memory tempStudent = ShortStudent({age: _age, income: _income, score: _score, attendance: _attendance, studentTranscript: studentTranscript});
        sstudents.push(tempStudent);


    }



    function getStudent (uint value) view returns (uint16, uint16, uint16, uint16, uint128, bytes32) {
        uint16 age = students[value].age;
        uint16 income = students[value].income;
        uint16 score = students[value].score;
        uint16 attendance = students[value].attendance;
        uint128 studentTranscript = students[value].studentTranscript;
        bytes32 studentAccount = students[value].studentAccount;
        return (age, income, score, attendance, studentTranscript, studentAccount);
    }

    function setEmployee(uint16 _age, uint16 _income, uint16 _timeWorked) public {
        Employee memory tempEmployee = Employee({age: _age, income: _income, timeWorked: _timeWorked});
        employees.push(tempEmployee);
    }

}
```

Geth -

```
> con.setStudent(1,2,3,4,5, eth.coinbase)
"0xd59b6a167272a6ab602dae7349df0bf122cc56d94ae2777a85e0df9db8713dfb"
> con.ssetStudent(1,2,3,4,5)
"0x22e1f793f9673be5e4aa924a12f949a1dae0fc0bf85004c4833d6e92f5a45680"
> eth.pendingTransactions.length
2
> eth.pendingTransactions.length
1
> eth.pendingTransactions.length
1
> eth.pendingTransactions.length
1
> eth.pendingTransactions.length
1
> eth.pendingTransactions.length
0
> con.students(0)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "0x"]
> con.students(1)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "0x"]
> con.sstudents(0)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>
```

It seems if the struct exceeds 32 bytes it does not update. I tested a few combinations. The ShortStudent updates but the Student does not. I would welcome any comments.

Txn -

```
> eth.pendingTransactions
[{
    blockHash: null,
    blockNumber: null,
    from: "0x46fb9a22689c4a4bfb494baeafbb8b2993725305",
    gas: 90000,
    gasPrice: 100000000000,
    hash: "0x5d47958fce451c03a2ca182dbaf06fc0b6e35e7d5e0da95cd696899cc8c5df7d",
    input: "0x0fdf453f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000546fb9a22689c4a4bfb494baeafbb8b2993725305000000000000000000000000",
    nonce: 433,
    r: "0x2de4055714d8f2d1563d24949e6a27363af4d593621dec42c287f8c2affc03a8",
    s: "0x416c421eaca32a5367675c1727652cde24d286bceb8936959bdeab1c89d65315",
    to: "0x302169699e3cca0d29eeafcd719b140ab5dfa590",
    transactionIndex: 0,
    v: "0x2b694",
    value: 0
}, {
    blockHash: null,
    blockNumber: null,
    from: "0x46fb9a22689c4a4bfb494baeafbb8b2993725305",
    gas: 90000,
    gasPrice: 100000000000,
    hash: "0x36ae9080e1a587798832b5abdf4fb29e0a7b890cf841b9945702cbf89490c88e",
    input: "0x0fdf453f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000546fb9a22689c4a4bfb494baeafbb8b2993725305000000000000000000000000",
    nonce: 434,
    r: "0x7646911758bb74e7f00afffd3925703cc09f89af8e5b9d25654a9512881201f5",
    s: "0x3bd856bcb093845adabb3fdf69db03b94c1cf9c66ae66d617e42cdc8f699351f",
    to: "0x302169699e3cca0d29eeafcd719b140ab5dfa590",
    transactionIndex: 0,
    v: "0x2b693",
    value: 0
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly that same code works for me.

I trimmed down the Solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract CA3 {
    struct  Student {
        uint16  age;
        uint16  income;
        uint16  score;
        uint16  attendance;
        uint128  studentTranscript;
        bytes32  studentAccount;
    }

    struct ShortStudent {
        uint16 age; 
        uint16 income; 
        uint16 score; 
        uint16 attendance; 
        uint128 studentTranscript;
    }

    Student[] public students;
    ShortStudent[] public sstudents;

    function setStudent (uint16 _age, uint16 _income, uint16 _score, uint16 _attendance, uint128 studentTranscript, bytes32 studentAccount) public {
        Student memory tempStudent = Student({age: _age, income: _income, score: _score, attendance: _attendance, studentTranscript: studentTranscript, studentAccount: studentAccount});
        students.push(tempStudent);
    }

    function ssetStudent (uint16 _age, uint16 _income, uint16 _score, uint16 _attendance, uint128 studentTranscript) public {
        ShortStudent memory tempStudent = ShortStudent({age: _age, income: _income, score: _score, attendance: _attendance, studentTranscript: studentTranscript});
        sstudents.push(tempStudent);
    }
}
```

Then I deployed it via Remix to `ganache` running on `localhost`. Then I ran the following JavaScript, using Node.js and web3.js 1.0.0-beta:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');

const abi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"students","outputs":[{"name":"age","type":"uint16"},{"name":"income","type":"uint16"},{"name":"score","type":"uint16"},{"name":"attendance","type":"uint16"},{"name":"studentTranscript","type":"uint128"},{"name":"studentAccount","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"sstudents","outputs":[{"name":"age","type":"uint16"},{"name":"income","type":"uint16"},{"name":"score","type":"uint16"},{"name":"attendance","type":"uint16"},{"name":"studentTranscript","type":"uint128"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_age","type":"uint16"},{"name":"_income","type":"uint16"},{"name":"_score","type":"uint16"},{"name":"_attendance","type":"uint16"},{"name":"studentTranscript","type":"uint128"},{"name":"studentAccount","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"setStudent","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_age","type":"uint16"},{"name":"_income","type":"uint16"},{"name":"_score","type":"uint16"},{"name":"_attendance","type":"uint16"},{"name":"studentTranscript","type":"uint128"}],"name":"ssetStudent","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}];
const address = "0x310477ec74c552ff68c76e8301ccb3f8c22724ce";

async function main() {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  const con = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address, { from: accounts[0], gas: 1000000 });

  console.log(await con.methods.setStudent(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, accounts[0]).send());
  console.log(await con.methods.ssetStudent(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).send());
  console.log(await con.methods.students(0).call());
  console.log(await con.methods.sstudents(0).call());
}

main();
```

The output was as expected:

```
{ transactionHash: ... }
{ transactionHash: ... }
Result {
  '0': '1',
  '1': '2',
  '2': '3',
  '3': '4',
  '4': '5',
  '5': '0x12a6f6cf1cc6e41ae93bca6cee813db9fb4e9d29000000000000000000000000',
  age: '1',
  income: '2',
  score: '3',
  attendance: '4',
  studentTranscript: '5',
  studentAccount: '0x...' }
Result {
  '0': '1',
  '1': '2',
  '2': '3',
  '3': '4',
  '4': '5',
  age: '1',
  income: '2',
  score: '3',
  attendance: '4',
  studentTranscript: '5' }
```

I would check that the deployed code matches the ABI you have, that `eth.coinbase` is a valid value that can be converted to `bytes32`, and that both of your transactions are actually succeeding. (You can check the transaction receipt via `eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash)`.)

Comment: This has to be deployment and gas issue then. I tested with various combinations and it fails when more than a slot of used. I saw remix stated "infinite gas." Maybe that is a factor. Otherwise it could be a geth issue.

Comment: I just added the txns in geth showing the gas and inputs.

Comment: I think you're not supplying enough gas. Try 150,000.

Comment: How is the gas changed? Does that require restarting with a new geth input? I saw new contracts can state the gas, but for a deployed contract using truffle I cannot see the gas option for contract execution.

Comment: Probably `con.setStudent(1,2,3,4,5, eth.coinbase, { gas: 150000 })`?

Comment: Brilliant. That worked. > con.students(0)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "0x46fb9a22689c4a4bfb494baeafbb8b2993725305000000000000000000000000"]